# Is it possible to create an enum class which contains objects of another non-enum class in Java?

Tags: java, enums

For example, I have `Subscriber` class and its objects `subscriber1`, `subscriber2`, `subscriber3`.
Is it possible to create an `enum` that contains these objects?
I'm trying to do this

```java
enum Subscribers{
    subscriber1,subscriber2,subscriber3;
}
```

But I'm getting strings `subscriber1`,`subscriber2`,`subscriber3` instead.
I would appreciate any feedback

Comment: Those aren't `String`s, they are `Subscriber` instances. Can you share a  [mcve] that highlights the problem?

Comment: enum type is static initialize type, you can't create the instance of object there

Comment: If your `Subscriber` class is supposed to only have 3 instances, that should be modelled as an `enum` itself. The enum constants are always objects of the type determined by the enclosing enum (which in turn derives from `java.lang.Enum`).
Can you show what your `Subscriber` class looks like and how those 3 `Subscriber` objects are declared? Maybe this is an XY Problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.** Enum constants inherit from the enum class.

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1):

> 8.9.1. Enum Constants
>
> The body of an enum declaration may contain enum constants. An enum constant defines an instance of the enum class.

In addition, constants aren't helpful if your subscribers can change after your code is compiled.

**However, you *can* do any of the following:**

- Create and fill a set of subscribers, using *`java.util.Set<Subscriber>`* -- e.g., with a `java.util.HashSet`.
- Make an enum of Subscriber *types*, and have each Subscriber hold a SubscriberType.
- Create static final fields of type Subscriber. (This isn't helpful if your subscribers can change after compile-time.)

Answer (score 2):

The value in an enum class are always of the type of the enum. Though you can also add fields and methods to your enum class:

```
enum Subscriber{ subscriber1("s1"),subscriber2("s2"),subscriber3("s3"); 

 private final String name;
 private Subscriber(String n) {
    name = n;
 }
 
 public void greet() {
   System.out.println ("Hello" + name);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define an enum:

```java
public enum Subscribers {
   subscriber1,
   subscriber2,
   subscriber3;
}
```

It means you define (i.e. from the given snippet) **3 singleton objects of class `Subscribers`**. In other words, this is absolutely normal instances like others (e.g. `new InputStream()`). And you are free to implement what you want in these classes.

```java
public interface Subscribe {
    void subscribe(Object obj);
}

public enum Subscribers implements Subscribe {
   txtFileSubscriber {
       private final InputStream in = new InputStream("foo.txt");

       public void subscribe(Object obj) {
           // implementtion
       }
   },
   xmlFileSubscriber {
       private final CsvReader reader = new CsvReader("foo.csv");

       public void subscribe(Object obj) {
           // implementtion
       }
   }
}
```

***P.S.** Given snippet is only to show how you can extend enum. This is very powerful feature.*